# MongoDB pushing to an object's array by object's index

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a user document with a `shelves` array field, in which are objects with `shelf_id` and `books` array.
How can I append to the `books` array given the `shelf_id`? (preferably in Python, but language doesn't matter)

My document structure is as follows:

```py
{
    "firebase_id": "(id)",
    "shelves": [{
        "name": "To read",
        "books": ["(book id)"],
        "shelf_id": "(shelf id)"
    }]
}
```

```py
db.users.update({"firebase_id": "(id)"}, {"$push": {}})
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [$arrayFilters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#up._S_%5B%3Cidentifier%3E%5D)

```
db.users.updateMany(
    {'firebase_id': '(id)'},
    {
        $push: {
            'shelves.$[elem].books': newBook,
        }
    },
    {
        arrayFilters: [
            {'elem.shelf_id': shelfId}
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Didn't know about arrayFilters! Thank you so much!